# Create a full TestSuite per interface or per Implementation

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I was wondering about what is the best practices to write tests if I have multiple implementations per interface.

 

 
Have I to replicate each test per implementations or I can create an abstract class that contains all tests about the interface and then create a simple test class per implementation that extends my abstract test class?

I am following "The art of unit testing" written by Osherove and he always repeat that we have to keep tests, and test suites, as simple as we can, so I don't know if adding an abstract class will increase the complexity of read tests by other developers.

Which one of the following example is commonly accepted and more readable?

Sample code:

```
public interface IMyInterface() 
{
    public string MyMethod(string input);
}

public class MyClassA : IMyInterface 
{
    public string MyMethod(string input) 
    {
        return input;
    }
} 

public class MyClassB : IMyInterface 
{
    public string MyMethod(string input) 
    {
        return "hello from MyClassB";
    }
}

public class MyClassC : IMyInterface 
{
    public string MyMethod(string input) 
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

TestSuite 1:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyClassATest {

    [Test]
    public void MyMethod_WhenCalled_ReturnsANotNullString() 
    {
        //arrange
        MyClassA sut = new MyClassA();

        //act
        string result = sut.MyMethod("hi");

        //assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
} 

[TestFixture]
public MyClassBTest {

    [Test]
    public void MyMethod_WhenCalled_ReturnsANotNullString() 
    {
        //arrange
        MyClassA sut = new MyClassB();

        //act
        string result = sut.MyMethod("hi");

        //assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public MyClassCTest {

    [Test]
    public void MyMethod_WhenCalled_ReturnsANotNullString() 
    {
        //arrange
        MyClassA sut = new MyClassC();

        //act
        string result = sut.MyMethod("hi");

        //assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

TestSuite 2:

```
[TestFixture]
public abstract class IMyInterfaceTest<TImplementation> where TImplementation : IMyInterface {

    [Test]
    public void MyMethod_WhenCalled_ReturnsANotNullString() 
    {
        //arrange
        TImplementation sut = new MyClassC();

        //act
        string result = sut.MyMethod("hi");

        //assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
}

[TestFixure]
public class MyClassATest : IMyInterfaceTest<MyClassA> {}
[TestFixure]
public class MyClassATest : IMyInterfaceTest<MyClassB> {}
[TestFixure]
public class MyClassATest : IMyInterfaceTest<MyClassC> {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try this approach using TestCaseSource (https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData). The advantage being you have one test instead of many repeating tests that do the same thing.

```
        [TestCaseSource(typeof(MyDataClass), "TestCases")]
        public void MyMethod_WhenCalled_ReturnsANotNullString(IMyInterface sut, string value)
    {
        //arrange

        //act
        string result = sut.MyMethod(value);

        //assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }

    public class MyDataClass
    {
        public static IEnumerable TestCases
        {
            get
            {
                yield return new TestCaseData(new MyClassA(), "hi");
                yield return new TestCaseData(new MyClassB(), "test");
                yield return new TestCaseData(new MyClassC(), "another");
            }
        }
    }
```